# Flutter Getting a specific Firestore document data and store it into a String variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from my Firestore and store the data into a String variable named time. Then put the variable into _event.

However, when I run the code, I got null, and I don't know why.

```
StateFulWidget...

String event;
Map<DateTime, List> _events;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

Firestore.instance.collection('events').document('2019-07- 
30').get().then((
    DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  event = ds['time'];
});

_events = {
  DateTime.parse("2019-08-01"): [event]
};
}
```

[This is my Firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rz1T.png)

I am new to Flutter and I have struggled for this question for a long time. Hope someone can help me

Thank you so much

**UPDATE**

I change my code.

However, I am still getting errors: The method [](Intance of 'DateTime') was called on null.

```
String event;
Map<DateTime, List> _events;

Future<String> getData()async{
final ds = await 
Firestore.instance.collection('events').document('2019-07-30').get();
return ds['time'];
}

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();

 getData().then((s) {
    event = s;
  //when I print(s), it showed the data correctly
  });


 _events = {
  DateTime.parse("2019-08-01"): [event]
 };
```

Can someone shows me where I got wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: time = ds.data["time"];

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this wrong, in my actual code, it is event all the time, there is no time variable in my actual code

Comment: Your Future isn't returning anything. Future<Map> getData....

Comment: I tried to use Future<Map<DateTime, List>>, but still showed errors

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting for the result, ie **_events = ..** will run before **.then()** clause and that is why **event** variable is still null;

.get() is a Future so you need to await the result.

```
final ds = await Firestore.instance.collection('events').document('2019-07- 
30').get();

event = ds['time'];

_events = {
  DateTime.parse("2019-08-01"): [event]
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't know where to put ds. Should I put it in initState or in the class? Also, I can't add await without async

Comment: Sorry, I am new to flutter

Comment: ds is created in the 1st line and used in the 2nd line. Put all this in its own method and return _events, and then call the method when you need the data.

Comment: I changed my code, however, it is still getting errors. Can you tell me where I did wrong? Sorry to ask you about this again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
Firestore().instance.collection('Collection Name')
.document('Document Name').get().then((data) async {
                     var dataReceive = data['property Name'];
                     }
```

Comment: This is async task u have to wait then u can use setstate method to update the UI after getting values